# Store Time only in SQL Server using C# as HH:mm AM/PM

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime

How can I insert only the time portion of a date into Sql Server from a `DateTime` structure in C#. I would like to save the time in the format of `HH:mm tt` (HH:MM AM/PM)

I have tried the following datatype's:

1. `time`
2. `timestamp`
3. `datetime`
4. `time(7)`

Sample Query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Reminder values ('" + txttitle.Text + "','" + txtdate.Text + "','" + txttime.Text + "','" + Txtmail.Text + "')", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And please don't store your datetime values as a character. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186724.aspx -> time is your best option though doesn't store AM/PM. An option could be to add another column with AM/PM in along side the time column? Edit: Use paramaters as Soner explained above!

Answer (score 5):

I think you misunderstand a few things..

Let's look at the C# side first. A [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains date and time values as a numbers. A [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx) is a *time interval*. This also keep these time values as a number. But interval word is important here because it does not have any date or other things like `DateTime`. It keeps this *time length* as a [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) under the hood.

On SQL Server side, native CLR `DateTime` mapped with [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx), [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) or [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) types and `TimeSpan` mapped with [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) type.

AM/PM designators are concept of a *textual* representation of a `DateTime` in [12-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) format. It is not a *part* of a `DateTime` value. It *may* belongs on a string representation of a `DateTime` value. A `TimeSpan` can't be represented with AM or PM because it is a *time interval*. That's why, you can't say as; *7 hours 3 minutes and 1 second after noon* as a `TimeSpan`. A `TimeSpan` *can't* be before noon or after noon. Because it is a **time interval**.

Let's look at your example;

Looks like you get your title, date, time and mail as a string from somewhere else. Here my suggestion;

If you **really** wanna show AM/PM designators when you try to represent them;

1. Concatenate your `txtdate.Text` and `txttime.Text` strings and [parse it to `DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx).
2. Save this `DateTime` value to your database with `date`, `datetime` or `datetime2`(preferable) typed column.
3. When you try to represent this value, select it from database, use `DateTime.ToString()` method with [custom date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?) specifiers (`tt` for AM/PM designator) with a specific culture. For example; `datetimeValue.ToString("HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way when you create dynamic sql commands. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also suggested reading: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); //Outputs 2014-04-08 12:50:35
now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); //Will then output 12:50:35
```